# Google map marker not showing in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

google map marker not showing in bootstrap modal.

this is my jquery code :

```
function map_init() {
  if(!$('body').data('map')){
      var var_mapoptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
          }
        };
    $('body').data('map',new google.maps.Map($('<div id="map"/>')[0],
            var_mapoptions));

    }
    return  $('body').data('map');
  }
  var Lat;
  var lon;
  $(document).on('click','a[data-map]',function(){
    var data=$(this).data('map'),
        map=map_init();

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = data;

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          } 
           Lat = latitude;
           lon = longitude;
         }); 
    $('#map_modal')
      .find('.modal-body')
        .append(map.getDiv())
      .end()
      .find('.modal-title')
        .text(data.Name)
      .end()
      .one('shown.bs.modal',function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter({lat:Lat,lng:lon});
                });
            })
      .modal('show');
  });
```

[image]

it's showing modal , but not showing the map marker. the latitude and longitude values are came from php code( that is from while loop value).

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that would add a marker to the map.  Why do you believe there should be one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not created any **[Google Maps Javascript API Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)** object.

> A marker identifies a location on a map. By default, a marker uses a
>   standard image. Markers can display custom images, in which case they
>   are usually referred to as "icons."

I would suggest to edit and add this code inside this line:

```
if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
  //add marker code here
}
```

code to be added:

```
var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
   positions : new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng() ),
   map: map,
   title: 'I am a marker :)'
});
```

And your Marker will appear.